# Ключевое слово inline

Tags: c++

Почему библиотечные функции часто имеют спецификатор `inline`, а в "обычном" коде его не встретишь?

Comment: Я как олимпиадник говорю, inline используется, но компиляторами обычно на него по барабану, нужно force_inline использовать:) А редко используется потому что компиляторы умные и сами разберутся что и как лучше делать.

Comment: Подтверждаю. inline - это пережиток тех времён, когда компиляторы были тупыми и когда считалось, что программист понимает машинную оптимизацию лучше компилятора. То же самое относится к слову register, которое сейчас вообще игнорируется или не работает. Сейчас почти в 90% случаев компилятор лучше знает, делать ли функцию Inline или нет.

Comment: @Zealint в целом да, но иногда магия с регистрами инлайном, махинации с утечками памяти позволяют ускорить код процентов на 20 которых как раз не хватало)

Comment: @pavel, пример покажите?

Comment: Для функций, определенных в `.h` файлах без `inline` не обойтись например (если заголовок используется больше чем в одной единице трансляции).

Comment: @ixSci поищу в логах, строки `void operator delete (void* A){
}
void operator delete[] (void* A){
}` меня часто спасали, а вот inline поищу конкретный пример.

Comment: @pavel, эти строки — понятно, Вы просто убили выделение/освобождение памяти, что является сильно тяжёлой операцией.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Спецификатор `inline` не означает, что функция будет встроена в точке вызова вместо реального вызова. Такими оптимизациями на текущий момент заведует компилятор и только он, он может встроить или не встроить любую функцию, без всякой связи с наличием или отсутствием `inline`.

Реальный смысл `inline` такой: сообщить компоновщику, что функции с одним именем, которые он видит в разных единицах трансляции — это одна и та же функция, и не нужно выдавать ошибку множественного определения. Таким образом, при помощи `inline` вы можете определять функцию в header'е. Заметьте, что методы классов, определённые внутри класса, имеют (неявный) `inline`.

Библиотечные функции содержат `inline` для того, чтобы можно было не определять тело функции в cpp-файле, при этом библиотека таким образом сможет вовсе не содержать файлов с имплементацией.

Comment: "методы классов, определённые внутри класса, имеют (неявный) inline" во что это выливается на практике?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: В то, что методы, определённые внутри класса, который определён в header'е, не вызывают ошибку multiple definition.

Comment: Ну это можно причислить к конструкции class, внутри которой они определенны. Впрочем это уже вопрос под каким углом смотреть.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Ну да. Но без этого правила («всё, что внутри класса, работает с неявным `inline`») пришлось бы делать ещё одно, специальное правило.

Comment: Вместо правила "методы классов, определённые внутри класса, имеют (неявный) inline" )

Comment: Мне казалось что inline там используется если он возможен, насколько  я помню если в функции есть цикл или более скольких-то переменных, inline  в целом невозможен, или это устарело?

Comment: @pavel: То, встроит ли компилятор функцию в точку вызова, таки да зависит от сложности функции. (И сейчас компиляторы стали намного умнее, и встраивают намного агрессивнее.) А ключевое слово `inline` можно ставить вне зависимости от содержимого функции.

Comment: Я понимаю что вне зависимости, просто оно тогда имеет смысл скорее аннотации а не реально свойства функции. А `__attribute__((always_inline))` и аналоги `__inline` `__forceinline` примеются в нормальном программировании? Не олимпиады и прочие попытки выжать из кода)

Comment: @pavel: Ну, как результат профилирования и тестов — почему бы и нет. Если это критичный по скорости кусок в числомолотилке. А без этого вряд ли, конечно.

Comment: @VladD, в теории всё так, на практике может получиться по другому. Лет 7 назад я сталкивался с багом gcc, который было очень сложно отловить: при добавлении одной строки в `inline` функцию, происходило что-то непредвиденное и малопонятное(что именно — я не помню, но баг из разряда «попробуй отыщи»). Т.е. длина функции, что-то ломала в gcc. Конечно, много воды с тех пор утекло, но кто скажет, что нет этих багов в современных компиляторах? Тем более, что явный `inline` нельзя назвать сильно распространённой техникой, тем более для больших функций.

Comment: @ixSci: Есть шанс, что это был не баг в компиляторе, а UB, и способность компилятора встроить функцию просто триггерила неопределённое поведение. Немного по теме: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Comment: @VladD, я не вижу основания для UB в стандарте. Размер функции в оном не лимитирован.

Comment: @ixSci http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/11450?locale=ru как люди ругались то когда узнали)  вот ещё http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/1059?locale=ru но тут UB видно, хотя и пишут так....

Comment: @ixSci: Я имел в виду, что в коде было UB _где-то_, и реальное встраивание кода открыло путь к UB-based-оптимизациям. Которые и привели к неожиданным эффектам.

Comment: Конечно, вопрос о С++, но возможно интересно, что в Си,  независимо от наличия `inline`,  к "одноименным" функциям в разных файлах все равно надо добавлять `__attribute__((weak))`  (в function declaration, иначе линкер ругается -- `multiple definition`)

Answer (score 3):

Наверное, зависит от того, чей код смотрите.

Я довольно часто пишу `static inline ...`, когда хочу показать (*прежде всего другим программистам, для компилятора `inline` совсем необязательное слово, просто hint*), что из соображений эффективности, желал бы видеть этот код вставляемым по месту использования (аналогично коду, определяемому в `#define`), но одновременно хотел бы, чтобы он был свободен от побочных эффектов расширения аргументов макро (из общих соображений возможных вариантов вызова).

Answer (score 2):

Определитель `inline` указывает компилятору, чтобы тот вставлял код функции в место, откуда она вызывается. Например

```
inline int quadrat(int x) {
   return x*x;
}

int main() {
   int y = quadrat(2);
   return 0;
}
```

Этот код будет скомпилирован в:

```
int main() {
   int y = 2*2;
   return 0;
}
```

Как правило, указать функции определитель `inline` можно, только если тело функции определено в заголовочном файле (`.h`). Если тело функции определено в файле `.c`, то компилятор проигнорирует этот определитель, и функция будет скомпилирована как обычная.

Comment: «Указание», это слишком громко сказано, «просьба», было бы куда точнее.

Comment: @ixSci а разве компилятор может пригнорировать инлайн?

Comment: @Flowneee, конечно: «_The inline specifier indicates to the implementation that inline substitution of the function body at the point of call is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism. **An implementation is not required** to perform this inline substitution at the point of cal_»