# Меняет ли встраивание (Inline) время жизни локальных переменных?

Tags: c++, функции, inline, локальные-переменные

```
inline int* x() {
    int x = 1;
    return &x;
}

int main()
{
    int* pp = x();

    std::cout << *pp;
}
```

Это будет UB? Inline помещает тело функции в caller, то есть локальная переменная x, уничтожается или изменяется её область видимости?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/548013/312941

Comment: @user7860670 Это не дубль, так как вопрос был не в том, является ли возврат указателя на локальную переменную UB (с этим ТС не спорил), а в том, не влияет ли на время жизни локальной переменной ключевое слово `inline`.

Comment: @Harry *" так как вопрос был не в том, является ли возврат указателя на локальную переменную UB (с этим ТС не спорил)"* - ничего подобного, ОП как раз спрашивает *Это будет UB?*. Это 100% дубликат. Как будет дубликатом любой вопрос про возврат указателя на локальную переменную. Иначе наплодятся вопросы про возврат из шаблонной функции, про возврат из метода, про возврат из const функции и т.п.

Comment: Чисто технически `inline` - это инструкция компоновщику, не компилятору. На производимый код и на смысл программы `inline` не влияет. Неопределённое поведение будет и c `inline` и без него.

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, `inline` не гарантирует встраивания.
Во-вторых, встраивание кода никак не влияет на время жизни переменных и т.п., подчиняясь принципу оптимизации, что с точки зрения работы программы как встроенный, так и невстроенный код должны вести себя абсолютно одинаково.

Поэтому в вашем коде время жизни локальной переменной никак не зависит от присутствия ключевого слова `inline`, а обращение к [уже не существующей] локальной переменной является UB.